# MySQL Query to replace text with variables in whole table

Tags: mysql

I'm using the following query to replace text in my database:

```
UPDATE `table_name`
SET `field_name` = replace(same_field_name, 'unwanted_text', 'wanted_text')
```

For example:

To replace this:

```
[url=https://www.example.com/folder/#code=variable&title=variable][img]https://example.com/images/image.png[/img][/url]
```

For this:

```
[url=https://example.com/folder/#code=variable&title=variable][img]https://example.com/images/image.png[/img][/url]
```

I use this query:

```
UPDATE `table_name`
SET `field_name` = replace(same_field_name, '[url=https://www.example.com', '[url=https://example.com')
```

But what I need to do is to replace the whole line (contains two variables):

```
[url=https://example.com/folder/#code=variable&title=variable][img]https://example.com/images/image.png[/img][/url]
```

For this:

```
[b]Success[/]
```

My problem is with the variables only.
What should I add to the query to perform this task?

Thanks in advance for your help

Note: MySQL version is: 5.6.x

Comment: Did you try to simple `replace(same_field_name, 'https://www.example.com', 'https://example.com')` or this strategy is not allowed?

Comment: That's what I did to remove the www from the url.
But what I need now is the remove the whole line (it contains two variables)

Comment: MySQL 8.0+ you can use `REGEXP_REPLACE`: `REGEXP_REPLACE('[url=https://example.com/folder/#code=variable&title=variable][img]https://example.com/images/image.png[/img][/url]', '\\[url=https://example.com.*?\\[/url\\]', '')` see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-replace